# TimeHandler in andengine interval after waves

Tags: android

I'm developing my first application and I just spawn monsters every 1 sec with TimerHandler.

I have different waves with different monsters and I want to pause the timer while the monster of the first wave go away or the user kill them and then spawn the monsters of the second wave.

Here is my code :

```
  private void createSpriteSpawnTimeHandler(){

     float mEffectSpawnDelay = 1f;



    spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay,true, new ITimerCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {



            if(wave > 0){
                 mTimePassed ++;
             }


             if(mTimePassed == 5){
                 wave*=-1;

             }
             if(wave < 0 && mMonstersAlive <= 0){
                wave *= -1;
                wave++;
                mTimePassed = 0;


             }
             switch(wave){
             case 1 :
                 createMonsterSprite();
                 break;
             case 2 : 
                 createMonsterSprite();
                 break;
             case 3 :
                 createMonsterSprite();
                 break;
             case 4 : 
                 createMonsterSprite();
                 break;
             case 5 :
                 createMonsterSprite();
             break;
             }


        }
    });
```

I do mMonstersAlive-- ,every time when the user hits monster or the monster is out of the screen.

I just want to pause the spawning when mTimePassed == 5 and then wait the monsters to go away or to be killed and then move to the next wave.

Some suggestions how to do that ,because I have no idea I wasted my whole day with this code.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you unregister the timer on your sprites,and reregister it when you need a new wave of monsters?

Maybe you can keep a count of how many sprites on the screen and when it reaches a certain number, unregister the timer, (that would be the first wave), then register it again when you need another wave